# P2P Voice Chat FP 10 rtmfp

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, p2p, voip, rtmfp

I am using Adobe Citrus and Air.
 The goal is to make a voice chat application with low latency. 
 I take the sound samples that I get from the Microphone SAMPLE_DATA_EVENT encode them in   using Native Process and speexenc.exe.

The question with method should I use for the sending of the samples. I tried object repication and the latency is to big.

Answer (score 0):

after your outgoing stream is connected imho the best choice will be:

```
outNetStream.attachCamera(Camera.getCamera());
outNetStream.attachAudio(Microphone.getMicrophone());
outNetStream.publish('media');
```